# Pir wiring to a existing light

Tags: electrical

Hi guys can anyone tell me which wire goes were on the light i have black blue qnd brown and on the sensor i have red blue brown any thoughts much appreciated please[image][image]

Comment: What does it say on the instructions - or those you could Google? A pic and make/model would help. As well as, is so often the case, location.

Comment: Likewise, pictures of how the light hooked up now - I'm going to guess UK location based on wire colors and football-club fandom ;-) But perhaps it's some other Chelsea (I seem to recall that Elvis Costello did not want to go there...) - Please [edit] to add those details and pictures.

Comment: Hi yes in the uk

Comment: How were the light wires hooked up before? Was it to a previous sensor, or is that the power input to the light?

Comment: The PIR is expected to have **Live** (brown), **Neutral** (blue), and **Switched Live** (likely red for that sensor). A light normally has just Live and Neutral (and either might also have Earth on a yellow-green wire.) A wire from a light to a sensor would be expected to have a switched live conductor as well, so that **might** be the black wire on the light, but it's difficult to determine without knowing what it was connected to previously.

Comment: Thanks for your help all it was connected previously was a sensor like this 1 as the old sensor broke being 30yrs old the new 1 is different wires

Comment: It would be nice to see inside that box, but I think Ecnerwal has guessed it correcrty.

Answer (score 2):

As you have now clarified that the wire pictured from the light was leading to a previous sensor, the most likely correct option is blue to blue (Neutral), brown to brown (Live), and red to black (Switched Live).

Comment: Yep this is the correct color code with the colors provided. Answere that are helpful should be up voted and a correct answer like this should get the green check mark so others can find it when looking for a similar problem.